# Problem with sorting data from database using DESC because of Ajax Filter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have problem with sorting data using DESC because I use Ajax Filter.

Data is showing correctly, but I want to sort them to show last added on top of the page. That's why I tried to add DESC, but problem is that I use Ajax filter and when I put DESC then nothing is showing up.

```
SELECT products.*, products_images.filename
FROM products
INNER JOIN products_images ON
(products_images.product_id = products.id)
WHERE products_images.product_id = products.id
AND products_images.id = (SELECT MIN(id)
FROM products_images
WHERE product_id = products.id AND product_status = '1' GROUP BY products.id)
```

All works until I add DESC at the end of this code.

Comment: Can you show us where you add `DESC`?

Comment: i add after brackets "GROUP BY products.id) DESC"

Comment: If you want it sorted you have to tell SQL which column to use. You can't just add DESC and hope for the best. Try something like `ORDER BY products_images.filename DESC`

Comment: Thanks, but this will sort products or product images?

I read something about rsort() function, maybe there is a way to rsort() all data on foreach?

Comment: What column do you want the data to be sorted on?

Comment: I want sort products by id.. 
to show last added on top of the page.

Comment: Where's the ajax for this? There's also no "php" here, only SQL and no `DESC` in it neither. If php/ajax isn't at fault, the then tags need to be removed if there isn't relevance, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

To make the results sorted descending on product ID try adding `ORDER BY products.id DESC` at the end:

```
SELECT products.*, products_images.filename
    FROM products
    INNER JOIN products_images ON
        (products_images.product_id = products.id)
    WHERE products_images.product_id = products.id
        AND products_images.id = (SELECT MIN(id)
            FROM products_images
            WHERE product_id = products.id AND product_status = '1' GROUP BY products.id)
    ORDER BY products.id DESC
```

Comment: i solve problem with rsort() function before foreach, but i also tried your method.

When i added "ORDER BY products.id DESC" that's worked well but axaj filter stoped work.

Comment: I can't see what you are doing with your AJAX. Your best choice should still be fetching the data from DB already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I added just rsort() to sort all products.
But **Dharman** method was great and worked well but with his method i was problem with ajax filer, to filter products.
Like cars, filter and show only BMW make or AUDI..
But this rsort() function works well and not conflicting with filter..

```
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$total_row = $statement->rowCount();
----ADDED RSORT-----> rsort($result); <-----
$output = '';
if($total_row > 0)
{

    foreach($result as $row)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is first part of code.
Let's name this file getdata.php

```
$query = "
SELECT products.*, products_images.filename..........";

 if(isset($_POST["carbody"]))
    {
         $carbody_filter = implode("','", $_POST["carbody"]);
         $query .= "
         AND carbody IN('".$carbody_filter."')
         ";
    }
```

and then is code in index.php page

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(carbody) FROM products WHERE 
product_status = '1' ORDER BY id DESC";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row)
{
?>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector carbody" value="<?php echo         
$row['carbody']; ?>"  > <?php echo $row['carbody']; ?></label><br />
<?php}?>
```

and then i have js at the end of index.php page...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    filter_data();

    function filter_data()
    {
        $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
        var action = 'fetch_data';
        var degviela = get_filter('degviela');
        var ser = get_filter('ser');
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch_data.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action, carbody:carbody, ser:ser},
            success:function(data){
                $('.filter_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function get_filter(class_name)
    {
        var filter = [];
        $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
            filter.push($(this).val());
        });
        return filter;
    }

    $('.common_selector').click(function(){
        filter_data();
    });
```

when i post your given code "ORDER BY products.id DESC" at the end of $query = "SELECT...." then index.php page doesn't show products, but with rsort($result); before foreach all works fine, products are sorted and checkbox filter products.